# How to combine two lists into a single list using Python

Tags: python, list

I've two lists comprising of multiple tuples inside them. I'm looking for a way to combine both the lists into a single list.

```
list 1 = [('mike','Company A','developer'),('steve','Company B','developer'),('tom','Company B','tester'),('jerry','Company A','tester')]

list 2 = [('mike','Company A','C++'),('steve','Company B','Python'),('tom','Company B','Automation'),('mike','Company A','Manual')]

Expected output:

list 3 = [('mike','Company A','developer','C++'),('steve','Company B','developer,'Python'),('tom','Company B','tester','Automation'),('mike','Company A','tester','Manual')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm very new to python programming. I came across this question and couldn't think of an approach to get the output

Comment: Does list3 = list1+list2 work for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two lists is easy:

```
list1 + list2
# [('mike', 'Company A', 'developer'),
#  ('steve', 'Company B', 'developer'),
#  ('tom', 'Company B', 'tester'),
#  ('jerry', 'Company A', 'tester'),
#  ('mike', 'Company A', 'C++'),
#  ('steve', 'Company B', 'Python'),
#  ('tom', 'Company B', 'Automation'),
#  ('mike', 'Company A', 'Manual')]
```

Then sort them.

```
>>> sorted(list1 + list2, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
# [('jerry', 'Company A', 'tester'),
#  ('mike', 'Company A', 'developer'),
#  ('mike', 'Company A', 'C++'),
#  ('mike', 'Company A', 'Manual'),
#  ('steve', 'Company B', 'developer'),
#  ('steve', 'Company B', 'Python'),
#  ('tom', 'Company B', 'tester'),
#  ('tom', 'Company B', 'Automation')]
```

Group them by the first two elements using `itertools.groupby`.

```
>>> groupby(sorted(list1 + list2, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])), key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
<itertools.groupby object at 0x7f77deb2f818>
```

Extract the third element from each value in each group using list comprehensions.

```
>>> [(k[0], k[1], [x[2] for x in v]) for k, v in groupby(sorted(list1 + list2, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])), key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))]
# [('jerry', 'Company A', ['tester']),
#  ('mike', 'Company A', ['developer', 'C++', 'Manual']),
#  ('steve', 'Company B', ['developer', 'Python']),
#  ('tom', 'Company B', ['tester', 'Automation'])]
```

From there it's just a matter of expanding thos lists out into each tuple.